# can't login to SSH with Bitnami Drupal AMI on AWS Marketplace

Tags: amazon-ec2, drupal

I have the Bitnami Drupal AMI that is on the AWS marketplace.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/ref=bill_eml_1?sku=5ysj40wf1vkv5qwu3jszwhefa

I can't SSH to it in EC2.

Tries to use user ubuntu.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE:

I found the answer to my own question here:

http://bitnami.org/tutorials/amazon_machine_images

Comment: Have you tried using ec2-user?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question here:

http://bitnami.org/tutorials/amazon_machine_images

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. If you were able to answer your question, please post the answer _in the answer section_ so that others know your issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm also running into this. Specified a keypair at the AMI creation but still unable to SSH in...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question here:

http://bitnami.org/tutorials/amazon_machine_images

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to watch out for with bitnami instances is that they come with the user `bitnami`.

If you are trying to SSH from terminal, make sure you're doing something like the following:

`ssh -i your.pem bitnami@12.345.67.89`